# Problem with a "hover" in one input[type="submit"]

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

Can anyone help me understand why my CSS styling is not being applied correctly to the input?

[.html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTQEy.png)
[.CSS styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4OoM.png)

I need to achieve a smooth transition with the CSS styles, but for some reason they are not being applied correctly.

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`

```
input[type="submit"] {
  background: #fff; 
  color: #4741d7;
  border: 2px solid #4741d7; 
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: large;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="submit"]::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #4741d7; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scale(0, 0) rotate(-180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover::after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `transition: all 0.3s ease` to `input[type="submit"]` and remove it from `input[type="submit"]::after` and `input[type="submit"]:hover::after`